# IIS7, SQL 2008 and ASP.NET MVC security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I'm working on. I've been developing it on Windows Server 2003 with IIS6 and SQL 2008 Express, and everything was working great. I recently decided to try out the Windows 7 beta, so now I'm using IIS7, and have run into a problem with connectivity to my database that I can't seem to figure out.

I can run/debug the app just fine, but whenever I try to access a page that needs to access the database, I get the following error:

"Cannot open database "MyDatabaseName" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName'."

I've obviously got some security configuration setup incorrectly, but I can't seem to find any good documentation on *how* to set it up correctly. I've tried giving NETWORK SERVICE permissions on the database, but that didn't seem to work. Anyone know what I need to do to give "IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName" permissions to this database? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are NOT using Active Directory, then ignore all of the other solutions mentioned here. The confusion stems from the new `ApplicationPoolIdentity` setting default in IIS 7.5+ (MS keeps changing the identity mechianisms)

1. Open **SQL Management Studio**, connect to your local machine as an admin.
2. Expand the **Security** branch.
3. Right click on **Logins** and select **New Login**
4. Into the **Login Name** field, type "**IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName**". Do *NOT* click the search button. The user profile dosn't actually exist on the local machine, it's dynamically created on demand.

While you're looking at it, don't forget to add the user to a database or a server role.

Comment: Do you leave the password as blank?

Comment: Create it as a "Windows Login" won't ask for a password.

Comment: "Do NOT click the search button" was the critical part for me, i knew to do the rest, but clicking the search button failed to find the user and i got stuck there..

Comment: This does not work when your SQL Server is on a different machine than IIS

Comment: Correct. If it isn't, and if you are not in an active directory, then you have to create a user account on the server hosting your SQL. If you use SQL authentication, then you can create a simple SQL account. If not, you can use a windows account with the same username and password as the user account that the website is running under, but the website has to be running as a user with "Login as a Service" permissions.

Answer (score 6):

The error means the web application doesn't have access to your database. On Windows 7 / IIS 7, by default each application pool has its own user. It seems the idea is to improve security by restricting what that web application can do (in case it gets compromised and controlled from the outside). You can change what user the application pool is running under but that will defeat its own purpose. A better way seems to give the pool's user the needed permissions (and not a bit more).

On the SQL Management Studio connect to the server you want your web app to connect (tested with SQL server 2008). Go to

```
Security -> Log ins
```

right click, New Log in. In the form that comes up leave everything as default except username, where you have to type whatever username the web app is trying to use, in this case 'IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName'. Note that the search function of that dialog fails to find or check as valid that user, but nevertheless it works.

Still on the SQL Management Studio connected to the server go to

```
Databases -> *YOUR-DATABASE* -> Security -> Users
```

right click and New User. I'm not sure if the user name field there has any effect, I just set it the last part of the username, like MyApplicationName. Then I've set the login name to IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName. You can click on the ... button and use the check and search, this time it works. If you don't do the previous step, the user will not be present here. Then give it whatever permissions you want to this user, like db_datareader.

And that's it, you've given permission. If lack of permissions was your problem, then it should be solved (or at least, I've just solved it that way).

**I have a total amount of 2hs of experience with IIS and about three weeks with SQL Server and less than two months with Microsoft technologies so take my advice with a grain of salt, I can be totally wrong**. (If another person can confirm these are the right steps, feel free to remove the last warning).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article that explains why AppPoolIdentities are in use; basically, it's about enhanced security: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

(That article claims I can use these virtual accounts just like any regular account but on my Windows Server 2008 that does not seem to be possible; adding e.g. IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool just produces an error: "The following object is not from a domain listed in the Select Location dialog box, and is therefore not valid.")

Answer (score 2):

Erick Falsken is right, however he is missing the User Mappings. So right click on the new 
IIS APPPOOL/DefaultAppPool, click on Properties and then check boxes for:
1) databases master and yourdatabase
2) db_owner and public

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that the user that your site is running as (or more to the point the application pool), does not have permissions to use the DB. You can either check in IIS what user the pool is running under and give them permissions, or instead change your SQL connection string to not use trusted authentication and supply the credentials of a user that does have permission in the connection string.

Edit:
If you right click on the pool Identity section and go to properties, it should come up with a box that lets you either choose from 3 builtin system accounts, or specify your own account. Either give one of the builtin accounts permission for the DB, or use an account that has permission. Or leave it as is and change your connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Well...changing the ApplicationPoolIdentity property and setting it to NETWORK SERVICE seems to have fixed my problems. Not sure if that's the "right" way to do things or not (as in, I'm not sure if that's the recommended way to do things in IIS7 or not), but it seems to at least be working and has gotten me past this hang-up for now. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, could you perhaps give some rep and maybe accept the answer?

Comment: im really trying to be constructive when i say this: but i've seen these type of security changes result in security holes for hackers. just because hours of faffing with security settings finally results in a combination of config that gets ur app to work, dont mean it's safe.

Comment: it just sounds like you've given inappropriate access to the App Pool

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to verify which account your website is running under. Create a simple aspx page with:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<% Response.Write(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name); %>
```

If you're using windows authentication the WindowsIdentity account will need to have a login in your SQL Server. Under Security -> Logins -> Login New you'll want to add whatever name that was displayed by WindowsIdentity and make sure Windows authentication is selected.

If you ever happen to move your database to a separate machine you'll have to create a domain account and use impersonation in your web.config. Google `<identity impersonate="true">` for more info.

Comment: Typo there. Lenguage => Language. I'd edit it, but I don't have enough points ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with the idea of giving permissions to the user that the application is running under...my problem is that in IIS7, the "user" seems to be virtual or something strange like that. Prior to me changing the "Identity" property of the Application Pool properties to NETWORK SERVICE, it was set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity", and the error I was getting was that "IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName" didn't have access to the database. When I attempted to add the "IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName" *user* to the database, it didn't appear to exist...not that I could find anyway.

So my ultimate problem is not understanding or being able to find any good documentation on how the IIS7 security model works. When I created the application, it seemed to create an AppPool with the same name just for this application. I don't know exactly what changes I need to make to give the application and/or the user it runs under privileges to the database, considering the fact that the user that the AppPool runs as doesn't appear to *actually* exist.

As I mentioned, changing the Identity of the AppPool to NETWORK SERVICE seems to have worked for now, but I'm trying to find out what the best practice is for this kind of thing under IIS7. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

leave the hard problems for someone else -

create a sql user and use SQL Auth. :D

Comment: Well that is the easiest way, is there any particular reason you have to use trusted authentication?

Comment: I understand, but I'm not trying to get away with the path of least resistance here...I'm trying to learn/understand the IIS7 security model. I'd like to understand how to get trusted security to work correctly.

Comment: please post your connection string

Comment: This is the *easiest* way; on the other hand it can provide security problems and also be against company policy.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow Mr. Fernández' advice, you will get everything working.  This is the new way of giving least privilege to a site.

So don't do the easy, less secure thing (NETWORK SERVICE).  Do the right thing.  Scroll up. ;)

Comment: My browser does not find Fernández or Fernandez anywhere in this page so I don't know what "the right thing" is except I assume it is not the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using Trusted Connection in Windows Authenticated Mode:
OS: windows 7 32 bit
IIS 7, Sql Server 2008 R2 Express
Connection String:
cn.open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=mycomputername\sqlexpress;" (if instance name is sqlexpress or whatever instance name you have used)

If you are not able to connect sql server using windows mode authenticated connection to sql server 2008.

NT AUTHORITY\IUSR Account might not have permission in sql server to authorize connection with database.

Connect Sql server using windows authentication mode.
Expand Security node.
Select NT AUTHORITY\IUSR (IF NOT THERE THEN ADD NEW LOG IN FOR THAT)
Click on "User Mapping" under Select a page at Log-in properties window.
Select the database that you are trying to connect.
Select following permissions from "Database role membership for:......" 
1. db_datareader 'this allows to open connection
2. db_datawriter 'this allows to fetch data records from datatable

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the description of the field it states that running under "Network Services" account is the recommended account to use. Not sure why in Win7 it defaults to the ApplicationPoolIdentity setting.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I'm running Windows 7 RC. When I'm trying to usa a .mdf file (located in App_Data), there is now way to make that thing work. I did try to change the AppPool's identity for LocalSystem, but it simply won't work.

If I use a "standard" database, then it will work if I'm using LocalSystem, but it won't work with the famous 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

I find it a bit disturbing not to find any information on that matter, it seems that the 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool' user is totally useless if you are using a database of any kind...

I have it running, but I'm also bit frustrated not to understand the security model, as stated by ryexley.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem between (SQL2008 that is installed on standalone Win-server2003 server) and (IIS6 with ASP.NET3.5 that are installed on standalone Win-server2003 server).

Where, IIS tries to access SQL2008 using some user in the domain "domain\username".

I removed following option out of connectionstring, and every thing works fine now.

```
Integrated Security=True;
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, the app pool identity method doesn't work like they say (not in IIS7 anyway) it's supposed to. I think there are hackers at MS who make this security convoluted on purpose so you take the path of least resistance and leave your system less secure (so they can hack into it later). - just kidding, but really, their security model is pure insanity, no straightforward (step by step) instructions anywhere on MSDN - nada, zip!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **SQL Management Studio**, connect to your local machine as an admin.
2. Expand the **Security** branch.
3. Right click on **Logins** and select **New Login**
4. Into the **Login Name** field, type "**IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName**". Do
   NOT click the search button. The user profile dosn't actually exist
   on the local machine, it's dynamically created on demand.
5. Select **Database** in **User Mapping**
6. Select **sysadmin** in **Server Roles**