# MVC 3 - After publishing to server - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

**Setup**

MVC 3 EF 4.1 Code First - Windows 7 Pro 64 Dev machine, Separate Win 7 Pro for host.

I started with a SQLCE4.0 database, and everything worked fine (database initializer created tables, populated, etc...).

Once I got everything working like I wanted, I scripted out my SqlCe DB, created a real SQL 2008 DB, opened the proper ports and enabled TCP connections.

**Problem** 
IF I Change my connection string to point to my intranet server\instance name, with a user I created for this app specifically, it works perfectly running from my dev machine.

IF I publish the app to the server (the web server and sql server are the same), and I try to login to the website (aka access the db), then I get:

***CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.***

I commented out the DBInitializer setup so nothing should be created upon a db hit. The tables are there already.

If I do Database.SetInitializer(null); then I get a different login error:

I don't remember exactly but it was something to the affect of ***LOGIN FAILED FOR IIS APPPOOL\ApplicationPoolIdentity***

So I changed the Identity to NETWORK SERVICE and even tried LOCAL SERVICE, both giving the same login failed error.

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454497/iis7-sql-2008-and-asp-net-mvc-security) post who says add a SQL user named 'IIS APPPOOL\MyApplicationName'. SQL Wont let me do that as it has invalid characters ... go figure.

*Why does it work perfectly over the network accessing the DB from my dev machine, but when I publish to THE SAME machine that hosts the sql and the site, I get permission denied or login failed errors?* I've scoured the net and tried different things.

EDIT: Here are my connection strings:

```
<add name="AntripContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|AntripWeb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <!--<add name="AntripSQL" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Antrip;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="AntripWebEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.csdl|res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.ssdl|res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\AntripWeb.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <!--<add name="AntripWebEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.csdl|res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.ssdl|res://*/DAL.AntripEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Antrip;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />-->
```

Note: The commented out connection strings are the ones that use the sql 2008 database (that break my published app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as if your connection string has Integrated Security=true so that you are connecting to SQL as the user you specify, rather than the SQL user you *think* you are using?

But beware, its still trying to create a database: you need to swap the IDatabaseInitializer - I guess it will look for a DB named the same as the entitys to be careful!