# My Mvc Codefirst Project working under iis Express but not in Local IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, code-first

I'm new to Mvc(Code First) , when I Use IIS Express Everything Working Fine But When Change That into Local IIS Getting Error at Line 52 .`

```
 using (OurDBContext db = new OurDBContext())
{
var usr = db.userAccount.Single(u => u.Username == user.Username && u.Password == user.Password);
             if(usr !=null)
  {
```

> Cannot open database "LoginCF.Models.OurDBContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "LoginCF.Models.OurDBContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Any how I've Configured Local IIS Already.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Check your DB connection string, it should include `Integrated Security=SSPI` or `Integrated Security=true` if you want to provide credential-based authentication.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  Thanks for your comment...this my `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OurDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MercedesDB;User Id=sa;password=xxxxxx; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: Your Data Source should be set to IIS host computer name instead of `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`, other parameters seems correct. Make sure the given DB also accessible by SQL server authentication mode.

Comment: My DataSource is Ip Address, For Security Reason I've used .(dot) here to show  you instead of Ip Address.

Comment: Try setting your Identity process model from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem` or `NetworkService` from IIS Manager => Application Pools => right click DefaultAppPool => Advanced Settings. It should work for local database.

Comment: Even though its not working @Tetsuya

Comment: After searching for a while, I found similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454497/iis7-sql-2008-and-asp-net-mvc-security. At this point you need to provide access by setting "Grant" and "Enabled" for `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` user in SQL Server for LocalSystem identity process model.